# How are files or chunks delimited on disk?

Tags: filesystems, osx, hard-disk, data-recovery, forensics

I'm trying to recover some lost files by `grep`-scanning a hard disk.  (The OS is Darwin 11.4.2.  The file system is HFS.)

How can I determine where a file (or contiguous chunk thereof) begins and ends on disk?  I'm thinking of something along the lines of a *generic* beginning-of-file (BOF) and end-of-file (EOF) sequences.

I'm hoping the search could automatically "parse" the scanned content into (at least) coherent chunks (by splitting it at BOF-or-EOF).

Comment: Did you try a higher-level file recovery utility first? What filesystem is this? ([HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)?)

Comment: The bof und eof are called headers and footers of a file, all in all a file signature. Here is a list: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @Anko: I did try a high-level tool (Wondershare Data Recovery) but it did not help (it seems to work only for recovering files of specific formats, such as media files).  The files I am trying to recover are all plain text files.  The filesystem is HFS.

Comment: There's no such thing as BOF or EOF "markers" on disk (for modern filesystems at least). They work with blocks or extents, indexed in potentially complicated ways. The blocks for a given file aren't guaranteed to be contiguous. File "chunks" are likely to start on block boundaries, but that's about all you can say generically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No general-purpose filesystem uses beginning-of-file or end-of-file sequences. They would be extremely impractical: what if a file contains these character sequences?

Most basic filesystems divide the storage into fixed-size blocks, and maintain a list of blocks for each file. The file size is kept separately, and how much of the last, partial block is used by the file is determined from that. Sophisticated filesystems refine this basic idea.

With [HFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System#Design), the list of blocks that make up a file's content is stored as extents in the file record and in the extent overflow file. The size of allocation blocks (the basic unbroken unit of file content) is stored in the filesystem header.